# Does iText create image-based or text-based PDF files?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I currently use iText for PDF generation and I am having difficulty determining if the PDF files generated with iText are text-based or image-based once generated.  Is there an easy way to determine that programmatically (or to specify one option or the other at the time of generation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iText generates PDF text instructions for text, and PDF image XObjects for images. Some other elements (e.g. borders) are generated as PDF graphics instructions. So I suppose you could say it generates "text-based" files.